# Insert / Select with different Values Possible in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to insert values in to the db.

```
INSERT INTO tblname(f1,f2,f3)
SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM othertbl
```

This would insert exactly the values **f1,f2,f3** from **othertbl**.

What i want to do is

**Inserting a different value for f2.**

How can i do that in MYSQL.

I hope i could explain my problem clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    tblname(f1,f2,f3)
SELECT  f1, othervalue, f3
FROM    othertbl
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what that *different* value is...

If you want to insert some known constant, you could use:

```
INSERT INTO tblname(f1,f2,f3)
SELECT f1,"foo",f3 FROM othertbl
```

If you want to insert the value at `f2` but double, you could use:

```
INSERT INTO tblname(f1,f2,f3)
SELECT f1,f2*2,f3 FROM othertbl
```

If you want to insert the sum of `f1` and `f3`, you could use:

```
INSERT INTO tblname(f1,f2,f3)
SELECT f1,f1+f3,f3 FROM othertbl
```

But I know those are probably the wrong functions to do the math, so I'll have to look up the right way to make my examples work, but the idea should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblname(f1,f2,f3)
SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM othertbl
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use string or math functions of mysql a/c ur needs

you can find them here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/non-typed-operators.html